# Rough patch in ironed surface

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura

I've been using the ironing settings in Cura to smooth the top surface on my prints generally with good results. However, I've been having problems with one model in particular recently where a small part of the surface is much rougher than the rest and visibly different.

I have tried printing the model several times and it happens in the same position each time, give or take a few millimeters. I'm using PLA filament on an Ender 3 V2. Ironing settings are 0.2 mm spacing, 10% flow, 16.66 mm/s. I've checked the extruder calibration and tried cleaning and replacing the nozzle without any improvement.

Can anyone suggest what is causing this and how to fix it?

[image: Rough patch on ironed surface of 3D print]